# How to run a block of code like using if and else statements or a replacement to if-else statement

Tags: r, if-statement

R noob here again. 
I want to prompt the user and according to user's choice I want to execute a block code.
So example;

```
install.packages("igraph")
library("igraph")

links <- read.csv("<path>.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
nodes <-read.csv("<path>.csv", header=T, as.is=T)


answer <- readline(prompt = " Enter s for straight c for curved lines ")
if (answer == "s") {
    variable <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes, directed=T)
    variable
    plot(variable, edge.arrow= .5, vertex.frame.color = "#ffffff")

} else {
    variable <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes, directed=T)
    variable
    plot(variable, edge.arrow= .5, edge.curved=.4, vertex.frame.color = "#ffffff")
}
```

Data for nodes:

`id,name,node.type,node.group
p1,Pi,Protein,1
p2,PPi,Protein,1
p3,SAM,Protein,1
p4,L-Met,Protein,1
p5,H2O,Protein,1
p6,SAH,Protein,1
p7,Ade-Rib,Protein,1
p8,LHCYS,Protein,1
p9,tetrahydropteroyltri-L-glutamate,Protein,1
p10,methyltransferase,Protein,1
p11,ATP,Protein,1
p12,Reaction 1,Reaction,2
p13,Reaction 2,Reaction,2
p14,Reaction 3,Reaction,2`

Data for edges:

`from,to,type
p13,p1,hyperlink
p13,p2,hyperlink
p13,p3,hyperlink
p4,p13,hyperlink
p5,p13,hyperlink
p11,p13,hyperlink
p12,p10,hyperlink
p12,p4,hyperlink
p8,p12,hyperlink
p9,p12,hyperlink
p6,p14,hyperlink
p14,p7,hyperlink
p5,p14,hyperlink
p14,p8,hyperlink`

This didn't work for me, switch cases didn't also work. Is there a solution for this kind of a problem?

I am pretty sure I didn't do any mistakes with my brackets.

Comment: I didn't get any error using your code (although I had to change the options in "a" for printing something)

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva Printing something doesn't cause an error and there are tones of examples on internet for if-else statements to print something but what I want to do is to execute a block code like in the example. I don't want to print anything.

Comment: I know. I said that because I don't have the variables "links" and "nodes", expected to work with your code. In that cause, I had to print something just to see if the code works. And it worked!

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva updated the question with data and complete if-else statement

Comment: Just a note: you'll hate yourself later if you don't call libraries at the beginning of your scripts.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen just noticed and corrected it, thanks a lot for the note

Comment: You should also comment out `install.packages` that's something you would typically do outside of your scripts.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I am trying to write an R package, I want 3 packages to download when someone gets my code (I am kind of merging 2-3 packages). Do you have a fancier solution to do this ??

Comment: Yes, there is a conventional way of specifying dependencies in an R package that does not require the use of install.packages nor library. Please see the section on depencies/imports: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html Also, in general, if this is your first time creating an R package you might be interested in the book or other contents associated with that link.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Yes, it’s my first time. Thank you for the link and the information. I always appreciate the better way to solve my problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the issue is that you're code isn't running immediately after a prompt, then I think a good solution would be to wrap your code into a function.

```
trial <- function(){
  answer <- readline(prompt = " Enter s for straight c for curved lines ")
  if (answer == "s") {
    variable <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes, directed=T)
    variable
    print(plot(variable, edge.arrow= .5, vertex.frame.color = "#ffffff"))

  } else {
    variable <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes, directed=T)
    variable
    print(plot(variable, edge.arrow= .5, edge.curved=.4, vertex.frame.color = "#ffffff"))
  }
}

trial()
```

Comment: It doesn't even prompt when I run every lines of code, it has a couple of install.packages

Comment: the above is just your code wrapped in a function, when you call the function it works. I added a print statement just to make sure it plots to the device

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're a life saver!